# Erro ao restaurar banco externo de aplicação asp.net mvc

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework

Estou tentando restaurar um banco `SQL` que criei em um provedor que não tem a opção *WebDeploy*. E meu objetivo é inicializar um base de dados utlizando `ASP.NET MVC` com `EntityFramework`. Bem, ao colocar as configurações de servidor e senha, o banco aparece no meu `SQL Management` Porém ele ficou diferente, no icone onde geralmente fica verde, está cinza segue uma imagem pra ilustrar melhor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao restaurar o *DB* tenho mais um erro, segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que é este erro?

Como faço para resolve-lo?

Aproveitando, enquanto estava desenvolvendo a aplicação, com `CodeFirst` eu utilizei a seguinte ConnectionStrings no meu `WebConfig`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="VendasDeTitulos" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VendasDeTitulos;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Como ficarei na configuração para utilizar com o banco do *Provedor*?

Answer (score 1):

A *connection string* precisa ser assim:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="VendasDeTitulos" connectionString="Data Source=mssql913.umbler.com,5003;Initial Catalog=VendasDeTitulos;User Id=usuario;Password=senha" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Não restaure o banco de dados manualmente. A aplicação que deve fazer isso.

Confira se seu `Web.config` tem o seguinte no momento da publicação:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="MeuProjeto.Models.MeuProjeto, MeuProjeto" disableDatabaseInitialization="false">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[MeuContexto, MeuProjeto], [Configuration, MeuProjeto]], EntityFramework" />
        </context>
      </contexts>
   </entityFramework>
<configuration>
```

Ou inicialize sua base por código:

```
public MeuContexto()
    : base()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MeuContexto>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MeuContexto, Configuration>());
}
```